# Is it possible to convert text to shape in VML /canvas/SVG?

Tags: 3d, canvas, svg, shapes, vml

I need to display a text in 3D using vml/canvas/svg and do some transformation to the shape of the text like the effect of Ctrl+T in photoshop, even align a line of text to a curve. For example, transform a normal text to a rotated, trapezoid/quadrilateral shape.

So, is there a way to convert text to shape first?

The only thing close is `getImageData()` in firefox which is not ideal but OK. Any better methods?

Using browser-specific hacks or voodoo is OK, but no Flash please :)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking for here.  In SVG, at least, you don't need to convert text to a shape to transform it.  The `textPath` element puts text on a path.  Is there a specific transformation you need to do to a part of one letter form?

Comment: @Ken

Your tip is very helpful, I am checking it out. 

About specific transformation, for example, transform a text to a rotated trapezoid form. Is it feasible?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like SVG 1.1 only natively supports affine transformations but not perspective projections.  It won't help you today, but they appear to be on the wishlist for SVG 2.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2Reqs/#req-graphics http://www.svgopen.org/2008/papers/86-Achieving_3D_Effects_with_SVG/#section_4_4_creating_perspective_effects_using_future_features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many stackoverflow posts, I think the best solution is to use inkscape.

So Javascript or HTML5 or canvas or SVG can not do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the skew transforms in SVG to do simple [isometric projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection). Same goes for HTML5 canvas. If you want other types of perspective projections there are ways to do that too, e.g multiple transforms combined with clipping, or with a SVG filter (see some examples by Hans Schmucker [here](http://www.tapper-ware.net/blog/?p=39)).